# Adding products in onepage

Tags: onepage-checkout, product-urls

I'm trying to add a simple shipping and handling fee apply when the customer chooses to ship to different address in onepage checkout. It does add the simple product to cart but it refreshes the page forcing the user to start over instead of progressing to the shipping information step. How can I add to the cart but progress to the next step?

```
<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(19580);?>
<input type="radio" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" id="billing:use_for_shipping_no" value="0"
<?php if (!$this->isUseBillingAddressForShipping()) {?> checked="checked"<?php }?> title="<?php echo $this->__('Ship to different address') ?>" 
onChange="setLocation('<?php echo (string)Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product); ?>').$('shipping:same_as_billing').checked = false;"
class="radio" />
```